# Change output text color in java

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, console

I'm trying to change the color of specific text in Eclipse's console, for example: regular text is in black, but errors are presented in red color. I'm trying to do the same with the `try` and `catch` blocks. Here's my code:

```
int [] arr = {1,2,6,8};

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
} catch (Exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    **System.out.println("You got too long");**
}
```

Now I want the code surrounded by double asterisks to be in red color in the console, is it possible? and if yes then how? Thank you.

Comment: Print to error stream `System.err.println`.

Answer (score 2):

Open Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Console and then change the colors as you like.

Comment: Your answer is missing the point. The op wants *"to change the color of specific text"* -- further, your answer is for C/C++ while the question is clearly about Java.

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow, The question doesn't mention "java" anywhere while it does specifically mention "Eclipse". It was my first search result to fix the output color in C++ in Eclipse's console, so I'd say the wrong question is being asked here.

Comment: @MasterHD I agree with you considering the question does not make use of the `java` tag, but considering that the code in question contains `System.out.println` and that the question is not about changing the color for every console output, but only for specific words (programmatically) I still feel like this answer is not correct.

Comment: @MasterHD I just added the `java` tag to avoid confusions and to prevent this question from showing up when someone searches for the output color of console text in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep console plugin for this. Check here for more [details](http://marian.schedenig.name/projects/grep-console/)

You can also filter/color eclipse console text based on regular expression.